# What does ANY mean in a dpctl dump-flows output

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow

I have created a controller with which I am trying to add some simple routing rules. One difficulty with doing this is how to interpret the output from the `dpctl dump-flows` command which outputs a lot of information that I dont really find relevant to determining the flow table.

```
*** MNSwitch ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 cookie=0x0, duration=208.891s, table=0, n_packets=8, n_bytes=784, idle_age=205, icmp actions=FLOOD
 cookie=0x0, duration=208.851s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=208, ip actions=ANY
 cookie=0x0, duration=208.851s, table=0, n_packets=8, n_bytes=336, idle_age=200, arp actions=FLOOD
```

I ran the command within a mininet terminal after running a topology python script. The controller script is also running.

I am trying to interpret this output. Mostly I am not sure what ip actions=ANY is supposed to mean. Am I blocking anything that isnt icmp, arp?